# NERDTreeTabs error message: E492: Not an editor command

Tags: macvim, plugin-nerdtree

I am using macvim Version 8.0.1098 (137) MacOS Sierra 10.12.6. I downloaded NerdTree tabs from [here](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs). I am using pathogen to manage my plugins. All the plugins work except this one. This is the error message I get when I type the command

```
:NERDTreeTabsToggle
```

I get the error

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>27_NERDTreeToggleAllTabs[7]..<SNR>27_NERDTreeOpenAllTabs[5]..<SNR>27_NERDTreeMirrorOrCreate:
line    7:
E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command:     silent NERDTreeMirror
line   12:
E492: Not an editor command:       silent NERDTreeToggle
```

Now if I install the simple NerdTree it seems to work totally fine. Any suggestions on how I can figure out what I might be doing wrong here?

Also when I open macvim now I get the error at the bottom which is

[image]

Comment: plugin error. Create an issue at the plugins page.

Comment: Except that plugin is no longer actively maintained, apparently. The author says he doesn't even use his own creation anymore. So maybe this one should be skipped.

Comment: From your question I'm not totally sure: did you install both NerdTree *and* NerdTreeTable? Because your error says that a NerdTree command doesn't exist which makes me think you didn't install NerdTree.

Comment: @statox I simply installed NerdTree Tabs using pathogen.

Comment: if you type `:NERDTreeMirror<c-d>` what does it show you?

Comment: `Ambiguous use of user defined command`

Comment: The first step in the ["installation" section of the README](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs#installation) says `If you haven't already, install NERDTree` and then install NerdTreeTab. NerdTreeTabs uses the plugin NerdTree, if it is not installed you get an error saying that a command you're trying to use doesn't exist.

Comment: ah ok. Ill install NERDTree looks like I missed that part

Comment: @Rajeshwar Would you consider to accept the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `Not an editor command: silent NERDTreeToggle` says that something is trying to use a command `NERDTreeToggle` but this command doesn't exist and Vim can't execute it.

`NERDTreeToggle` is a command defined by the plugin [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) which seems to indicate that the plugin is not installed.

Now when you read the very first line of the [installation section in the README](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs#installation) you'll see

> 1. If you haven't already, install NERDTree (see https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree)

Thus if you install the plugin you should get rid of these errors.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was an option `'on' : 'NERDTreeToggle'` config in the vim-plug section:

```
Plug 'https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree', {'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
```

After removing this section all works fine:

```
Plug 'https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree'
```

Comment: Correct answer!